# android how to place two slidingdrawer handler beside each other

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

(solved by myself)
Need some advice on how to do this.
To clarify i Added two pictures showing the two slidingDrawers on the left side.
They are by default overlapping so i changed one image to the android-icon to see the problem better.

For reference
[Im Using this Drawer custom widget created by Alessandro Crugnola](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/) 
for my two drawer you see on the image left side.

I know by default the handler are position centered and need advice
on how to put them beside each other vertically.
They must take up hole screen as picture show.

I have tested layout_weight="1" and also putting them inside a LinearLayout
But that give me a half size drawer. I pretty much understand that the default
slidingdrawer cannot do this so the question is what kind of hack will do this.

Is there a way to do this?

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

**(UPDATE WITH HOW IT CAN LOOK WHEN TWO IMAGES OVERLAP, se detail in discussion below)**

[image] [image]
MY XML:

```
    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/imageEditGallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spacing="2px"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etx_addtext_drawtext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Enter text here"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.bulk.sprise.editimage.SlidingDrawerLeftFriends
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bulk.sprise"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_drawer_left_friends"
        my:direction="leftToRight"
        android:layout_width="280dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        my:handle="@+id/handleLeftFriends"
        my:content="@+id/content"

        >
        <include
            android:id="@id/content"
        layout="@layout/drawer_left_friends_content_editimage" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handleLeftFriends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/drawer_left"
            android:topOffset="10dip"
        />
    </com.bulk.sprise.editimage.SlidingDrawerLeftFriends>

    <com.bulk.sprise.editimage.SlidingDrawerLeftOptions
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bulk.sprise"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_drawer_left_options"
        my:direction="leftToRight"
        android:layout_width="280dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        my:handle="@+id/handleLeftOptions"
        my:content="@+id/content"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@id/content"
        layout="@layout/drawer_left_options_content_editimage" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handleLeftOptions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:topOffset="40dip"

        />
    </com.bulk.sprise.editimage.SlidingDrawerLeftOptions>



    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout_container_SlidingDrawerRight"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >

        <com.bulk.sprise.editimage.WrappingSlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerRight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButtonRight"
            android:content="@+id/contentLayout2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@null">

            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/slideHandleButtonRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/drawer_right"
                android:onClick="btnSlidingDrawerHandler">
            </ImageButton>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/contentLayout2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@null"

                >

                <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_A"
                    android:layout_height="60dip"
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                    android:text="Button_A"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/plus_ball"
                    android:onClick="btnAListener"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY">
                </ImageButton>

                <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_B"
                    android:layout_height="60dip"
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_A"
                    android:text="Button_B"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/text_ball"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:onClick="btnBListener"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY">
                </ImageButton>

                <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_C"
                    android:layout_height="60dip"
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_B"
                    android:text="Button_B"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/delete_ball"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:onClick="btnCListener"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY">
                </ImageButton>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </com.bulk.sprise.editimage.WrappingSlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working myself.
This is tested and working for anyone who need it.
Have not tested it on different screen sizes.

Create two handler images.
For hdpi one is 58x400 and the other is 58x132.
On the big one place the graphic on the lower part so the top part is transparent.
The other image handler must look like a normal handler.

just arrange your two slidingDawer's in the xml so that
the larger image(slidingDrawer) comes first.

Also you need to do bringToFront() on the smaller handler,
if gui changes place it behind the larger handler

That's it

Comment: This may work, but the user experience can be really bad. What if the user pulls accidentally from the transparent part? How should we handle this? But yes, test this out and see what works.

Comment: your right, one image will alway lay above the other. That has to make the other image inaccessible. Maybe some gesture detection on the transparent part and set do bringToFront().

Comment: yea looks good one image is 58x400 in hdpi and the other is 58x132. @omermuhammed They are overlappig but visually it looks like two button (updating my question). I can of course only pull out the larger one. Is there a way to configure the transparent part on the large image so i can touch the image underneath?

Comment: I haven't tried it but in the transparent area of that image it should be possible to define a region and on clicking that region we do onFocusChange() call and make the second sliding drawer button come into focus.

Comment: thanks that sounds promising. I got it kind of working dunno if it's stable, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Lets call both sliding drawers sd1 and sd2. One idea (untested) to address this, would be to have custom images for the handler, and have one sliding drawer (sd1) visible, and other (sd2) hidden (with visibility set to "gone").

And then, in your view, right at the edge where the sd1 handler is displayed have an image (button or plain image) of sd2 handler image right next to it. This will make the UI seem like there are 2 sliding drawers waiting to be pulled out.

So now, when the user pulls out sd1 it works according to design. When he clicks the other image, that makes sd2 visible and it gets pulled out. That way you can have both sliding drawers.

Potential complication of this approach are:
1. Untested
2. You may need a custom view to have the sd2 handler image exactly next to sd1 handler.
3. Handling this approach on different devices with different screen sizes may be tricky.

Comment: when sd2 is pulled out the custom image for sd2 must also be pulled out. That can be tricky to do. Your probably right about complications for other devices. This could work but i have need for it to be stable on all devices.

Comment: No, the custom image can be strategically placed button, and we can then set its visibility to "View.GONE". About support on different devices, if you align sd2 with bottom of the screen then the sd1 can be relative and its position easily managed. If you do choose to go this way then just setup all possible emulator configurations (10-15) and test this on them. Dont need a handset for that.

Comment: cannot get my head around this, im still an android amateur.  The code to pull out sd2 is for my very hard to do. It has to feel the same as sd1 and a normal slidingDrawer

Answer (score 0):

oh here we go again with another possible solution

What if i have two slidingDrawer inside a LinearLayout and position them
with `layout_weight="1"` and `layout_hight="0dip"`.

This will force them to even the hight and i have two drawers
evenly spaced vertically on the left side.
They will not have full hight of course but i dont want to use them
so they both have empty dummy_layout.xml.

What i want to use is there nicely and evenly positioned handler images.

now, I take my question xml code above and put that in as well and make
the handler images `view.gone`.something....

Now there ar four slidingdrawers on the left sida. Two invisible and two visible.
Now i have the mechanism for the two drawer handlers and they
will work on all devices right.

what i see is two drawers right.
If i pull them there must be some way to redirect the pull to my
desired full hight drawer hidden behind.

I think one could set the dummy-drawer invisible but pull the handel as usual.
By doing so trigger a `drawer.open()` on the real one underneath.

maybe im way-out there and please correct me if im wrong.

are you following..

Comment: This looks like it will work. The other question is how maintainable this code is, because.. it looks really convoluted. Maybe you are better off taking the sliding drawer code and creating a custom component that supports 2 sliders next to each other?